# Check Username exist in Angular2 & Sails

Tags: angular, sails.js

Im Using Angular2 as front end and Sailsjs as Backend. When user is registering I need to check whether username already exist. To do that sails backend will issue json response after checking the database. json responses are as below:

If not exist

```
{
  "status": true
}
```

If exists

```
{
  "status": false
}
```

Now I want to output a boolean value in angular2 service

```
CheckUsernameNotExist(username){
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:1337/userAPI/usernameExist', JSON.stringify({ username: username}))
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(
            (data) => {return data.status},
            (error) => {
                alert('Error getting user Details');
            }
        );

    }
```

in the register() call it should work with if

```
if(this.userservice.CheckUsernameNotExist(user.username){
 console.log('username exist')}
```

But this code does not work. Can you kindly help.

Comment: In subscribe do you get desire data?

Comment: yes when i put console.log(data.status) in subscribe it prints true or false

Comment: try this - `CheckUsernameNotExist(username){
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:1337/userAPI/usernameExist', JSON.stringify({ username: username}))
            .map((res: Response) =>return res.json().status)
}`

Comment: I tied CheckUsernameNotExist(username){
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:1337/userAPI/usernameExist', JSON.stringify({ username: username}))
            .map((res: Response) => { return res.json().status } )  with  console.log(this.staffservice.CheckUsernameNotExist(staff.username)) and it returned Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator, lift: function, subscribe: function, …}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CheckUsernameNotExist(username){
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:1337/userAPI/usernameExist', JSON.stringify({ username: username}))
            .map((res: Response) =>{return res.json().status)}
        );    
}

register(){
  this.userservice.CheckUsernameNotExist(user.username).subscribe(data=>{
        if(data){  //<<<< here you'll have true or false
          //do something
        }else{
          //do something
        }
  })
  console.log('username exist')}
}
```